# How can I open a Microsoft Word document from within a winforms .exe app?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms app that utilizes a dll (docX) to create a .docx document from a StringBuilder. I'm trying to open that document with Microsoft Word (the default program) with a button click. I tried the folowing code but I keep getting errors. Can someone point me in the right direction to accomplish this?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var x = "";
        using (DocX document = DocX.Create("Testdocx.docx"))
        {
            document.MarginTop = 25f;
            document.MarginBottom = 25f;
            document.MarginLeft = 25f;
            document.MarginRight = 25f;
            Paragraph p = document.InsertParagraph();
            FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Courier New");

            p.Append(sb.ToString()).Font(fontFamily).FontSize(8); //where "sb" is a StringBuilder
            document.Save();
            x = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        }
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\WINWORD.EXE";
        startInfo.Arguments = x + "\\Testdocx.docx";
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

Comment: `Can someone point me in the right direction` Step 1 - Tell us what errors you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach hard-codes the path to WINWORD.  While this may work for your case, it is inflexible and brittle.

You can instead simply do

```
Process.Start(x + "\\Testdocx.docx");
```

That will find the default document handler for .docx files (which is Winword, assuming it is installed and you have not installed anything else that handles .docx files).

Answer (score 1):

Just change 3 lines in your code. Your problem will be solved

here...

```
using (DocX document = DocX.Create(Application.StartupPath + "\\Testdocx.docx"))
```

here

```
document.Save();
x = Application.StartupPath;
```

.
and here

```
startInfo.Arguments = "\"" + x + "\\Testdocx.docx\"";  // -> Quotes on either sides
```

.

.
Also I think you dont need to give full path for Word. Just do

```
 startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD.EXE";
```

Or even just

```
 startInfo.FileName = "WINWORD";
```

Comment: Thank you I tried all your suggestions. Now it's opening the Word Program but it gives me an error loading the document- "problem with the contents". Also, it only works from within Visual Studio, not when I try executing from an external exe.

Comment: can you show what you've put on your StringBuilder?

Comment: I tried with some sample String like Welcome to Stackoverflow, and there wasn't any error

Comment: It's basically a whole bunch of appended strings that are variables taken from a list of strings. Like this:sb.Append(Spacer(7) + list[2] + "\r\n\r\n"); //landlord
            sb.Append(Spacer(7) + list[3]); //landlord address
            sb.Append(Spacer(60 - (list[3].Length + 7)) + list[4] + "\r\n"); //affixed on premises date
            sb.Append(Spacer(8) + list[5]); //city

Comment: Might be some unsupported character or something. Have you tried with some simple string?

Comment: Have you put quotes between the filename as said above?

Comment: Also test it with C:\TestDocx.docx

Comment: I just noticed that this question on stackoverflow  is concerning the same error message:    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17675526/how-can-i-modify-the-foreground-and-background-color-of-an-openxml-tablecell

Comment: I think this answer is eligible for an upvote by giving you some knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Arguments passed includes : Application , location

```
 Process.Start("winword.exe", "C:\\you path here \\filename.docx");
```